# Group by multiple columns as if it was one column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Is there a way to group by multiple columns as if the columns were united in C# using Linq?

Let's say I have an object that represents a message sent from one user to another:

```
public class Message
{
    public Int32 SenderId { get; set; }
    public Int32 RecipientId { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentAt { get; set; }
}
```

I get a set of these from repository and then I have to order them by sent date and filter out by pair `SenderId, RecipientId`. But I want to get back only the very last message from a given dialog between two users. The direction doesn't matter, so

```
(SenderId == 1 && RecipientId == 2)
```

should be treated as

```
(SenderId == 2 && RecipientId == 1)
```

So far I got this:

```
Messages
    .GroupBy(m => new { m.SenderId, m.RecipientId })
    .Select(gm => gm.OrderByDescending(m => m.SentAt).FirstOrDefault());
```

But the problem with this approach is when I have a message sent from user 1 to user 2 and vice versa 2 => 1, both will be returned. Because Key (1,2) isn't the same as (2,1).

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

UPD: I should've added that I'm using the expression with IQueryable expression. So it's LINQ to Entity.

Comment: Which .NET and C# version are you using? You can convert the key into tuple and use custom comparer for that

Comment: I use .net core 2.2 and whatever version of C# goes with it. But it doesn't support the tuples. But if I won't find the solution I'll upgrade. Could you please give an example?

Comment: actually it supports tuples, you can try to change `(m => new { m.SenderId, m.RecipientId }` to `m => (m.SenderId, m.RecipientId)` and check, how it works

Comment: It underline my code and says "An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal."

Comment: It's VS Code and netstandard2.0 library which accordingly to this table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version by default uses C# 7.3. I don't really understand why then I cannot use the named tuples.

Comment: You can use value tuples in *code*. You can't use them in *expression trees* (similar to `?.` operator for instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you tagged your question [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework), not everyone seemed to understand that many in-memory solutions fail because they don't have a SQL equivalent. Here's a query that will translate into SQL for many different `IQueryable` implementations and query providers:

```cs
Messages
    .GroupBy(m => new
    {
        MinId = m.SenderId <= m.RecipientId ? m.SenderId : m.RecipientId,
        MaxId = m.SenderId > m.RecipientId ? m.SenderId : m.RecipientId
    })
    .Select(gm => gm.OrderByDescending(m => m.SentAt).FirstOrDefault());
```

Using `Math.Min` / `Math.Max` will only work in Entity Framework core 2, because this is the only EF version that auto-switches to client-side evaluation for any part of the query that doesn't translate into SQL. This was abandoned in EF core 3. EF core 3 only applies client-side evaluation in the final projection (`Select`), if necessary. So the `GroupBy` will fail in EF core 3, which you're going to use sooner or later.

However, I have to warn you that currently, this won't work in EF core 3, because they don't support `GroupBy` fully yet. But I'm sure that's a matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

GroupBy accepts a [custom equality comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__). You could implement your specific matching logic there like so:

```
class MessageComparer : IEqualityComparer<Message>
{
    public bool Equals(Message x, Message y)
    {
        return (x.SenderId == y.SenderId || x.SenderId == y.RecipientId)
        && (x.RecipientId == y.RecipientId || x.RecipientId == y.SenderId); // i guess you can go as specific as you like here, depending on your requirements
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Message obj)
    {
        return (obj.SenderId ^ obj.RecipientId).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

in your calling method, do something like so, with a custom comparer:
    `Messages.GroupBy(m => m, new MessageComparer())
    .Select(gm => gm.OrderByDescending(m => m.SentAt).FirstOrDefault());`

UPD: using LINQ to Entities will change the solution quite a bit then. You are right, custom functions and equality comparers will not be supported by EF as it needs to translate this to SQL somehow (even if you manage to do it, your query performance will likely take a nosedive due to lack of functional indexes). I see a couple of avenues to explore:

1. select all messages for both users with no grouping and apply grouping in C# (where you've got your custom comparers and can do pretty much anything like so: `Messages.Select(gm => gm.OrderByDescending(m => m.SentAt).ToList(/*DB call happens here */).GroupBy(m => m, new MessageComparer()).FirstOrDefault()` - this however potentially fetches a lot of data from the DB so you will need to consider filtering
2. change your database schema to introduce a **SequenceNumber** column that will be shared between sender and recipient and you can use that in SQL will all indexes you like
3. write a stored proc that does some sort of trickery on your two columns and gives you desired output (for example you could sort two integers and concatenate them to produce one value that you then rely on).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It compiled but I got NotSupportedException saying: "Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Message]).[Includes].GroupBy(m => m, __p_0)': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy' is currently not supported."

Comment: right, I updated the answer with some ideas to explore. see if any of that would appeal to you?

Comment: I agree with all of these except the former one. Since there might be lots of messages I don't want to bring up all of them to memory for nothing as I do the pagination after I'm done with filtering. I almost started to write the sp but one of the answers did it. Thank you for the suggestions anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Since both Id's are integers, you can order them in your group by:

```
Messages
    .GroupBy(m => new { Math.Min(m.SenderId, m.RecipientId), Math.Max(m.SenderId, m.RecipientId)})
    .Select(gm => gm.OrderByDescending(m => m.SentAt).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I slightly changed the expression, because it was complaining on names of properties: .GroupBy(m => new { X = Math.Min(m.SenderId, m.RecipientId), Y = Math.Max(m.SenderId, m.RecipientId)})
But it now gives me Exception with message "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source". I am trying to figure it out right now.